# Object identification in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, collision-detection, tree-structure

I am making a collision detector in JavaScript. I want to make a tree structure so that I can make a complex object.

There is one big array and all the objects including children are part of the array.
Some of them are child and others are parents. Each item has `children`, `parent` and `root` property and if a collision happens, it bubbles up to the parent.

I came up with 2 ways to identify objects.

1. Give objects IDs
2. Quote object directly like `"node1.root = someOtherObject"`.

I also want to know which is faster

```
//1
if(object1.root === root.id){/*code here*/}//id based identification (literally)
        //19253 === 19253

//or 2
if(object1.root === root){/*code here*/}//object based identification
     //[Object] === [Object]
```

Comment: It probably won't make much of difference, if any. I'd say just use what you think is the easiest to maintain and most readable.

Comment: two objects can't be equal `{} === {}` output `false`. So consider giving property in the object.

Comment: The difference in performance will be negligible. I think comparing object references is technically the right way to go, but you might end up wanting ids as well just for debugging purposes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/886053/74757) for further explanation.

Comment: I am going to compare if the objects are exactly the same. I understand that '({}==={})===false" and "({"bar":"foo"}==={"bar":"foo"})===false'

Answer (score 1):

Both will be same in respect of performance. Please check below link.

http://jsben.ch/#/Y9jDP